# How to generate a .txt file with form data and download it with Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, download, writefile

The system has a form, on the side of the backend I recover that data, what I can't do is download that data in a .txt file.

I was using `fs.writefile ()`, but when the system is uploaded in the cloud it does not access the destination folder.

```
   var new_ingreso = new Ingreso(req.body);
   //I want to download the data from req.body in a file.txt
   fs.writeFile(
      'nameFile.txt',
      new_ingreso.nameUser,
      error => {
        if (error)
          console.log(error, 'el archivo no fue creado');
        else
          console.log('El archivo fue creado');
        });
  }
```

The file is created without problems what I want is to know if there is any way that this file can be downloaded or if there is another way to download.

He's seeing a way but I'm not sure how to continue.

```
var file = fs.writeFile(....);
```

Comment: You are currently only reacting to error

Comment: What I am trying to do is generate a .txt file with data from a form in react and download it using nodeJs.

Comment: fs.writeFile writes a file on the server.  You need to generate that content and then return that as the response to the POST request (or some other API call you make from the browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a route like this. You need to do something with the file path to find your file. No security, code not tested, but it gives you the idea of how to do it.

See https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

```
get('file', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile('nameFile.txt', options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', 'nameFile.txt')
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: great, your input is very useful